# How is the universe both non-ergodic and quantum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, ergodicity

From Ted Jacobson we know relativity is thermodynamical. This also (I think?) must mean relativity, as a classical analysis, assumes space-time to be ergodic, i.e. a system that can reach thermal  equilibrium and ‘forget’ its initial conditions, aka ‘no deep history’, or alternatively, no external time.

Non-ergodic systems on the other hand, do not visit all of their possible states, and do have ‘history’. Rather like the absolute time of quantum mechanics. However, it seems to me that there is a general consideration that quantum mechanics is *also* ergodic, (e.g. von Neumann) but -

Q) The universe is *[clearly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PX9RfvTWeJU)* non-ergodic (like human individuals), and so how can QM be ergodic?

Note – I also came across [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0512178) paper, maybe related

Comment: I think Sean Carroll in your linked video, uses the word ergodic as synonym for uniformly distributed. Whereas you, and many others, use it as a synonym for a system that undergoes thermalization. The reason for this latter use is that, in classical mechanics, ergodicity of the Hamiltonian dynamical system implies thermalization. Note that in QM there is no ergodic dynamical system but people still use the word ergodic as a synonym for thermalization.

Comment: The summary (1.09 in the video) is that if the universe (a closed system) was ergodic (defined as a system that cycles through every allowed state - which is the regular definition, not a synonym) then the rest of the system, no matter what we observe locally, should be thermal equilibrium (max entropy).  Since this is nonsense (look out the window) then the universe is not ergodic. Thus, 'something is wrong with the assumption of QM and finite dimensional Hilbert space'.  So re 'no ergodic dynamical system in QM' are you saying QM is not ergodic?

Comment: Mr Anderson, his definition of ergodic QM system which is given around minute 49 (that the eigen energies are rationally independent) *does not* imply thermalization. The conditions under which a QM system thermalizes are a subject of current research and are more subtle than in classical mechanics (where that condition could be taken as ergodicity)

Comment: @lcv Research like [ETH] https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.01616 Thanks.

Comment: precisely. This is exactly what I meant. If you are interested in the connection between ergodicity (or its definition) and thermalization in QM i suggest https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.02336

Comment: QFT is non-ergodic. It deals with relativistic open systems for with classical ergodicity doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

General relativity and quantum mechanics are both *models* of reality. They are very successful models, in that their predictions very closely match the results of experimental observations, and no known observations contradict either model.

However, neither model can be a complete model of reality because they are inconsistent. GR is a classical deterministic model in which any set of parameters can, in principle, be determined to any degree of precision. QM is a stochastic theory in which there are limits to the precision with which certain pairs of parameters can be simultaneously measured. One aspect of this difference gives rise to the [black hole information paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox).

I am not sure what you mean when you say that the universe is "clearly non-ergodic". Do you mean it is clear that information is lost ? Yes, parts of the universe (such as each human being) lose information, run down and decay, but they are not closed systems. Information may still be conserved across the universe *as a whole*.

Comment: Thanks, not really addressing question though. Sure, GR and QM are inconsistent. As to BH info paradox, while perhaps not universally accepted, I think that is solved [Adami] (http://adamilab.blogspot.com/2013/11/black-holes-and-fate-of-quantum.html). Re univere non-ergodic, plz see above.

Comment: The universe as we observe it now is clearly not in thermal equilibrium. But the universe is still very young (compared to the lifetime of stellar mass black holes, for example). It may reach thermal equilibrium in the distant future. So I still don’t see how the current state of the observable universe leads you to conclude that its fundamental laws *must* be non-ergodic.

Comment: @gandalf61 The universe was nearly in thermodynamic equilibrium before it became transparent to the CMB. That equilibrium, however, is not a true equilibrium in a scenario in which gravity starts accreting matter while new space is being created constantly. Since the creation of new space is constantly going on, the universe will most likely never be in a true equilibrium, no matter what happens otherwise. Naive 19th century thermodynamics concepts simply don't apply here.